# Unknown column 'Extent1.Discriminator' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity, membership-provider

I am using Visual Studio 2013 web form application with MySql database to build a web form application but I have been unable to get past 'Membership and Role Management'.
I used a database first approach for the membership and when I try registering a new user, I get the error message below:

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unknown column   'Extent1.Discriminator' in 'where clause'

Source Error: 


Line 16:             var manager = new UserManager();
Line 17:             var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = UserName.Text };
Line 18:             IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text);
Line 19:             if (result.Succeeded)
Line 20:             {

Source File:     c:\WebsiteProjects\ASPNETWebProjects\RevenuePortal\RevenuePortal\Account\Register.aspx.cs
```

Strangely, I do not have an 'Extent1.Discriminator' column anywhere in the database and cannot understand the reason for this frustrating error.

Comment: As an added note to anyone in the future who's encountering this issue: if you let your debugger break on the line in which the query is being executed, and inspect the your table's property on the db context you'll see the SQL the EntityFramework has generated. For me this was incorrect, and I could easily pinpoint that one of my column names was incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extent1 is a table alias used by entity framework when it constructs the underlying sql statements. The error means that EF is either not configured correctly or misinterprets your database structure.

You need to analyise the underlying query it generates and determine why EF us3s a field it is not supposed to. Probably a relationship between 2 tables is incorrectly set up.

Comment: Thanks Shadow. I allowed ASP.net generate the database table which resolved the problem

Comment: Possible errors include missing or misnamed columns / properties.

Comment: Do you have any more information as to what configurations could be incorrect?

Comment: I encountered this problem when trying to make one db model inherit from another, while overriding the [Table] attribute. My solution was to get both of my models to inherit from another base class which is not scaffolded

Answer (score 0):

if possible try to do migration from beginning. from below execution in Nuget package manager:VS 2019 - Tools - NuGet Package Manager - Package Manager Console - run command `Add-Migration DBInit` - once done, run another command `Update-Database`.

Above solution is for code first approach.

I had same issue when I changed my system, After did migration it started working for me. Hope same will work for others. happy programming!!