# Entity Framework code first , Lambda to mysql query fail

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, lambda, code-first

I try to write lambda expressions query and its allways fail with Exception :

```
Unknown column 'Extent1.PSPID' in 'where clause' .
```

When i google it i found this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32939018/5818398

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong ?

**This is the lambda expressions:**

```
ctx.PSPPrioritiesConfigurationSet.Where(
                    priority =>
                    priority.PaymentServiceProvider.PSPConfigurationByPSList
                                  .Where(pspPs =>
                                    pspPs.PaymentService.Code == serviceCode      &&
                                        pspPs.PSActivation.Where(
                                            activation =>
                                            activation.WhiteLabelId ==   whiteLabelId &&
                                            activation.IsActive
                                        ).Any()
                                       ).Any()

                     ).ToList();
```

**This is the wrong query that the EF build :**

```
 SELECT
`Extent1`.`Id`, 
`Extent1`.`PSPID`, 
`Extent1`.`WhiteLabelId`, 
`Extent1`.`PriorityRank`, 
`Extent1`.`Percent`
FROM `PAYMENT_Priorities_Configuration_PSP_WL` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT
1 AS `C1`
FROM (SELECT
`Extent2`.`Id`, 
`Extent2`.`PSID`, 
`Extent3`.`Id` AS `Id1`, 
`Extent3`.`Code`
FROM `PAYMENT_Configurations_PS_PSP` AS `Extent2` LEFT OUTER JOIN `PAYMENT_Service` AS `Extent3` ON `Extent2`.`PSID` = `Extent3`.`Id`
 WHERE (`Extent2`.`PSPID` IS NOT NULL) AND (`Extent1`.`PSPID` = `Extent2`.`PSPID`)) AS `Project1`
 WHERE (`Project1`.`Code` = @p__linq__0) AND (EXISTS(SELECT
1 AS `C1`
FROM `PAYMENT_Activation_PS_PSP_WL` AS `Extent4`
 WHERE (`Project1`.`Id` = `Extent4`.`PsPspId`) AND ((`Extent4`.`WhiteLabelId` = @p__linq__1) AND (`Extent4`.`IsActive` = 1)))))
```

**This is the relationship :**

```
           #region  PSPConfigurationByPS Foreign Keys

        modelBuilder.Entity<PSPConfigurationByPS>()
            .HasMany(m => m.PSPLocalizationByPSList)
            .WithOptional(m => m.PspConfigurationByPS)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.PsPspId);


        modelBuilder.Entity<PSPConfigurationByPS>()
            .HasMany(m => m.PSActivation)
            .WithOptional(m => m.PspConfigurationByPS)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.PsPspId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PSPConfigurationByPS>()
             .HasMany(m => m.PsFinancialInstitutionList)
             .WithOptional(m => m.PspConfigurationByPS)
             .HasForeignKey(m => m.PsPspId);

        //one-to-many 
        modelBuilder.Entity<PSPConfigurationByPS>()
                    .HasOptional<PaymentService>(m => m.PaymentService)  // PSPConfigurationByPS HasOptional PaymentService 
                    .WithMany(m => m.PSPConfigurationByPSList)  // PaymentService entity includes many PSPConfigurationByPS entities
                    .HasForeignKey(m => m.PSID);

        //one-to-many 
        modelBuilder.Entity<PSPConfigurationByPS>()
                    .HasOptional<PaymentServiceProvider>(m => m.PaymentServiceProvider)  // PSPConfigurationByPS HasOptional PaymentServiceProvider 
                    .WithMany(m => m.PSPConfigurationByPSList)  // PaymentServiceProvider entity includes many PSPConfigurationByPS entities
                    .HasForeignKey(m => m.PSPID);

        #endregion

        #region  PSPPrioritiesConfiguration Foreign Keys

        //one-to-many 
        modelBuilder.Entity<PSPPrioritiesConfiguration>()
                    .HasOptional<PaymentServiceProvider>(m => m.PaymentServiceProvider)  // PSPPrioritiesConfiguration HasOptional PaymentServiceProvider 
                    .WithMany(m => m.PaymentServicePriorities)  // PaymentServiceProvider entity includes many PSPPrioritiesConfiguration entities
                    .HasForeignKey(m => m.PSPID);


        //one-to-many 
        modelBuilder.Entity<PSPPrioritiesConfiguration>()
                    .HasOptional<WhiteLabel>(m => m.WhiteLabel)  // PSPPrioritiesConfiguration HasOptional WhiteLabel 
                    .WithMany()  // WhiteLabel entity includes many PSPPrioritiesConfiguration entities
                    .HasForeignKey(m => m.WhiteLabelId);

        #endregion

        #region  PaymentServiceActivation Foreign Keys

        //one-to-many 
        modelBuilder.Entity<PaymentServiceActivation>()
                    .HasOptional<WhiteLabel>(m => m.WhiteLabel)  // PaymentServiceActivation HasOptional WhiteLabel 
                    .WithMany()  // WhiteLabel entity includes many PaymentServiceActivation entities
                    .HasForeignKey(m => m.WhiteLabelId);

        #endregion
```

**EER:**

[image: EER]

**The Entities :**

```
public class PSPPrioritiesConfiguration
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? PSPID { get; set; }
    public virtual PaymentServiceProvider PaymentServiceProvider { get; set; }

    public long? WhiteLabelId { get; set; }
    public virtual WhiteLabel WhiteLabel { get; set; }

    public int PriorityRank { get; set; }
    public int Percent { get; set; }
}



public class PaymentService
{
    public PaymentService()
    {
        PSPConfigurationByPSList = new List<PSPConfigurationByPS>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Code { get; set; }
    public string Logo { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PSPConfigurationByPS> PSPConfigurationByPSList { get; set; }


}


public class PaymentServiceProvider
{
    public PaymentServiceProvider()
    {
        this.PSPConfigurationByPSList = new List<PSPConfigurationByPS>();
        this.PaymentServicePriorities = new List<PSPPrioritiesConfiguration>();

        this.PSPCountriesConfigurationList = new List<PSPCountriesConfiguration>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public PaymentServiceProviderCode Code { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PSPConfigurationByPS> PSPConfigurationByPSList { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PSPPrioritiesConfiguration> PaymentServicePriorities { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PSPCountriesConfiguration> PSPCountriesConfigurationList { get; set; }
}




   public class PSPConfigurationByPS
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? PSPID { get; set; }
        public virtual PaymentServiceProvider PaymentServiceProvider { get; set; }
        public virtual PaymentMethod PaymentMethod { get; set; }
        public int? PSID { get; set; }
        public virtual PaymentService PaymentService { get; set; }
        public string ServiceName { get; set; }
        public string FinancialInstitution { get; set; }
        public virtual bool AllCurrencies { get; set; }
        public virtual bool AllCountries { get; set; }

        public PSPConfigurationByPS()
        {
            this.PSActivation = new List<PaymentServiceActivation>();

            this.PsFinancialInstitutionList = new List<PsFinancialInstitution>();

            this.PSPLocalizationByPSList= new List<PSPLocalizationByPS>();
        }

    public virtual ICollection<PaymentServiceActivation> PSActivation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PsFinancialInstitution> PsFinancialInstitutionList { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PSPLocalizationByPS> PSPLocalizationByPSList { get; set; }

}


public class PaymentServiceActivation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? PsPspId { get; set; }
    public virtual PSPConfigurationByPS PspConfigurationByPS { get; set; }

    public long? WhiteLabelId { get; set; }
    public virtual WhiteLabel WhiteLabel { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

**Mapping Tables:**

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<PaymentService>().ToTable("PAYMENT_Service");
        modelBuilder.Entity<PaymentServiceProvider>().ToTable("PAYMENT_ServiceProvider");
        modelBuilder.Entity<PSPConfigurationByPS>().ToTable("PAYMENT_Configurations_PS_PSP");
        modelBuilder.Entity<PSPPrioritiesConfiguration>().ToTable("PAYMENT_Priorities_Configuration_PSP_WL");
        modelBuilder.Entity<PaymentServiceActivation>().ToTable("PAYMENT_Activation_PS_PSP_WL");
        modelBuilder.Entity<PSPLocalizationByPS>().ToTable("PAYMENT_Localizations_PS_PSP");
```

**Thanks a lot !**

Comment: can you please check is this column is null

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69922

Comment: could you please post your column mapping code as well?

Comment: You mean the entities ? @YaserAdelMehraban

Comment: Yap,  I guess something is wrong in your mappings...

Comment: @YaserAdelMehraban Updated ! thanks.

Comment: I meant which entity is mapped to which table (just those with PSPID)

Comment: @YaserAdelMehraban Updated!.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129335/discussion-between-gal-koren-and-yaser-adel-mehraban).

Comment: ok i'm in the chat.